# Best way to fix an out-of-sync TFS workspace after a back-up/restore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, version-control

Wednesday I had to restore from a back-up image I made on Monday.   At the time of the snapshot I had about 20 files modified, which I later checked in, and more, on Tuesday.   Now that I am back to a snapshot from Monday morning, my workspace has all of these files checked-out or added, etc. even my check-in comments and work-item associations.  But I already did that check-in on Tuesday.

I'm thinking I will shelve all the pending changes  (just in-case), and then just undo all changes, and get latest (specific version).   And I should be back to good.

Any cautions or suggestions?

(TFS 2008, VS2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you checked everything in before you restored, and the TFS server has the right versions of all the files, you may be safer just to delete your workspace and make a new one.

This will make sure everything is where it should be, and you won't run the risk of something accidentally getting overwritten or modified when you didn't want it to.

Comment: That's a great idea.  That was very quick and clean.